# Quota limitations too strict or am I doing something wrong?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api, quota

I'm trying to create a dynamic report page with Google Analytics Embed API.
Currently I have about 10 separate charts which tend to cause problems.

First of all it is slow to update the charts if I change a view or a filter etc.
Secondly, if I do it "too fast" it will stop and return error about quota limitations.

For me it seems that this API is quite useless if it hits quotas with such usage: one report with ten charts.
However, I ended up wondering that am I doing something wrong?
Or can localhost cause some of these problems?

The whole report is based on Javascript so no server side solutions.
I've set quotaUser property in query object since this solution is to be integrated into Intranet.

Comment: Please post the quota which you are hitting.  If you want to harness the full potential of the Google Analytics API you should be using the Reporting API and not the embedded API.    Then embed api is not meant for large reports.

Comment: The [limits and quotas](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/limits-quotas) are well documented; You can make upwards of 10 requests per second to a single view. The slowness could probably be optimized, through lazy evaluation, batching your requests or shortening the date range.

Comment: Hi! I just tried reporting api v4 but I don't have a clue that how am I supposed to render the data as a chart? There's no single example on how this json data from reporting api could be used as data for a chart. I found one Python example where all result data has to be mapped with either google visualization library or other 3rd party. So, there isn't integration between these google "products"; reporting and visualization?